# Code Optimisation - remove this expression which always evaluates to "true"

Tags: c#, list, optimization, sonarqube

I am trying to optimize the code using SonarQube

```
List<string> itemList = serviceObject.GetItems();
```

I tried to validate the list with the below code

```
if(itemList != null && itemList.Any()
{
     //Some operations
}
```

when above code executed I am getting Sonarqube error **remove this expression which always evaluates to "true"**
So I refactor the code as

```
if(itemList == null || !itemList.Any())
    return;
//Some Operations
```

when above code executed I am getting Sonarqube error **remove this expression which always evaluates to "false"**

Could anyone let me know what is wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried to replace the part `= serviceObject.GetItems()` with `= null` and see what happens. Maybe something inside the `.GetItems()` method ensures that it's not null? Still it seems like an odd warning.

Comment: can you post the complete code.

Comment: @JakobBuskSørensen unless nullable reference types are enabled, in which case `itemList` can't be null.

Comment: Which C# version are you using? Have you enabled Nullable Reference Types by adding `#nullable enable` in the file or `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` in the `csproj` file?

Comment: What type serviceObject.GetItems() is returning? . by error it means itemList  is always null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can shorten this to

```
if (itemList?.Count >0)
{
...
}
```

or

```
if (itemList?.Any() ==true)
{
...
}
```

`?.` is one of the [Null conditional operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) (the other is `?[]`), the `Elvis operator` for short, that allows you to access potentially null variables without throwing. The result of the entire expression after the Elvis operator is nullable and returns `null` if the variable is null.

This means that `itemList?.Count` returns an `Nullable<int>`, and `itemList?.Any()` a `Nullable<bool>`. `Nullable<T>` defines relational operators between itself and its base type T but can't be used as T without an explicit cast. That's  why `(itemList?.Any() ==true)` is needed.

If you use [Nullable Reference Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) though, `itemList` can't be null, so a simple comparison would be enough:

```
if (itemList.Count >0)
{
...
}
```

If you enable Nullable Reference Types by setting `#nullable enable` in a source file or `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` in the `csproj` file, the compiler ensures that all variables, fields and methods that return reference types are *not* null, forcing you to either fix the problem or explicitly specify that a variable is nullable.

With NRTs enabled this line :

```
List<string> itemList = serviceObject.GetItems();
```

Would only compile without warnings if `GetItems` never returned a null. If the compiler doubts this, it would issue a warning advising you to either fix the problem or explicitly declare `itemList` as nullable with  :

```
List<string>? itemList = serviceObject.GetItems();
```

Comment: I think of the same, but not implemented as I thought it handles True case only and may  results in SonarQube code smell. To my surprise it passed SonarQube. Lesson learned instead of thinking will it works of not, better try it and get conclude. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is due to null Comparision.

`itemList != null`

There is a high chance that `serviceObject.GetItems();` is guaranteed to not return null by having a `[NotNull]` Annotation. Hence the null check is redundant.

[How can I show that a method will never return null (Design by contract) in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484571/how-can-i-show-that-a-method-will-never-return-null-design-by-contract-in-c-sh/484598)

Comment: The `NotNull` attribute in C# has little to do with Code Contracts, which are more-or-less abandoned. It's used with NRTs to [help the compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis) when it can't determine the nullability of a result or value. In this case, with NRTs, `List<string>` means the variable can't be null. If `GetItems` returned `List<string>?` the compiler would generate a warning

Comment: NotNull is a resharper thing, not a C# thing (any more), right?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes you are right about the nullable reference type and the explanation I gave is misleading.

Answer (score -1):

if( itemList !=null ) {//Do something...}

Comment: The expression checks for 1 or more items, not just null

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos If you know then post right ans.

Comment: I did, 20 minutes ago, explaining what's going on and how to shorten the expression

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos  I am having doubt but nobody answering me... if i found help by uh... it will be easy for me

Answer (score -2):

```
List<string> itemList = new List<string>();
itemList = serviceObject.GetItems();
if(itemList!=null && itemList.Count() > 0 )
{
     //Some operations
}
```

Count is enough to validate a list

List will always not be null but will have no elements. but you have to instatiate it so it wont throw an exception.

Comment: You cannot invoke any methods (like `Count()` if the list is not instantiated, i.e. if it's `null`). Hence to use `Count()` or `Any()` you must first ensure that the list is not null.

Comment: @JKC what Jakob said is right. we cant expect the service not return null. Its better to check for null

Comment: The new List<T> will always not be null if instantiated so Count works just fine if instantiated,  it will also be good for  code reusability

Comment: Careful with Count(); it can be a performance disaster in some cases; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305092/which-method-performs-better-any-vs-count-0

Comment: @JKC creating a new list only to discard it is wasteful. You can't call `itemList[0]` if the list has no items. What you wrote will throw a confusing `IndexOutOfRangeException` if `itemList` was null

Comment: The point Jakob is making is "how can you be absolutely sure that `serviceObject.GetItems()` did not return null?" - if it does, your code explodes. Your edit doesn't address this in any way, it's just making an incorrect answer worse

Comment: @CaiusJard if serviceObject.GetItems() returns a List without a value it will never be a null https://dotnetfiddle.net/75Sa36

Comment: @JKC but it can return a `null`. In which case your code would throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException`. The question is why the check evaluates to true, and how to simplify the expression.

Comment: @JKC that is not the point I'm making at all. Here are the ways your code explodes: https://dotnetfiddle.net/JX5NzG https://dotnetfiddle.net/prqKJq https://dotnetfiddle.net/ydpvCo , and that's even after fixing the error that your code won't compile because Count is a property of list, not a method (your fiddle didn't import LINQ). There's no point making a new list only to overwrite it with return value of GetItems, and even if you did `itemList = service.GetItems()?itemList;` it would *still* blow up because a new list doesn't have an item at [0]